# How to set creator for this Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have to create social network like Twitter people post tweet but has comment in it. I defined

```
var Comment = new Schema();
Comment.add({
    title     : { type: String, index: true }
  , date      : Date
  , body      : String
  , created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});


var TweetSchema = new Schema ({
        created_at : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    ,   created_by: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    ,   title : String
    ,   comments : [Comment]
    ,   body : String
    ,   picture: [Url]
})
```

Because I write for mobile application request through REST api I provide
I want to ask, when I create a tweet, what can I send to server to have creator_info and comment to? I have read [something here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it). But I don't know how to write a method to create a tweet or comment and set creator for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do. Before saving a tweet, you try to create a User from the data. if it fails, pass the error. If not, set the created_by field to be the user's id.

Look here for more info: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
TweetSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = new User(this.created_by, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    this.created_by = user._id;
    next();
  });
});
```