# How to populate a "sub document" (Doc_1.Doc_2 -> Doc_3)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate a "sub document", the idea is to build the object which enables the path `Session.Groups[0].Members[0]._user.pseudo (Session.Groups -> User)`, here is what i tried, 2 different methods, with 2 different issues:

- The first one doesn't populate anything (not even the "first document (Groups)").
- The second one give me `Session.Groups[0].Members[0]._user === null` **after** i populate.

I have seen an answer about how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it), but it doesn't work in my case.
I just have updated mongoose to the v3.8.0.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  pseudo: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
)};
Db['User'] = db.model('User', UserSchema);

var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Members: [ 
    { _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, points: { type: Number, required: true, default: -1 } },
    { _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, points: { type: Number, required: true, default: -1 } },
    { _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, points: { type: Number, required: true, default: -1 } }
  ]
});
Db['Group'] = db.model('Group', GroupSchema);

var SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
  Groups: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
});
Db['Session'] = db.model('Session', SessionSchema);
```

**CASE #1**

```
Db['Session']
.find()
.populate('Groups.Member._user') // I get anything populate (not even the Groups).
.exec(function(err, Sessions) {
    var nb_populated = Sessions.length;
    for (var Session in Sessions)
        Sessions[Session].populate('Groups.Members._user', function(err, Res) {
            if (err)
                console.error('Error when populating Groups.Members._user');

            nb_populated--;
            if (!nb_populated) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(Res.Groups)); //Here, i just get the Groups ids
                res.send(200, Res);
            }
        });
```

**CASE #2**

```
Db['Session']
.find()
.populate('Groups')
.exec(function(err, Sessions) {
    var nb_populated = Sessions.length;
    for (var Session in Sessions)
        Sessions[Session].populate('Groups.Members._user', function(err, Res) {
            if (err)
                console.error('Error when populating Groups.Members._user');

            nb_populated--;
            if (!nb_populated) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(Res.Groups)); //Here, every Members._user become `=== null` (wasn't befor the `populate()` call).
                res.send(200, Res);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have a simple blog project and there is subdocument inserting operation. You can have a look at here https://github.com/cubuzoa/expressSimpleBlog#3-insert-subdocument . Hope it helps

Comment: @cubuzoa Thanks for your help, but if i understand your example correctly, you have only 2 differents Models, in my case, it's like you have a "sub-sub-model" in your "sub-model", and you want to populate it from the model.

Comment: In that case, you will have 3 models and embed 3rd to 2nd model after that embed 2nd one to 1st model. You can populate it easily. Construct your submodels and push 3rd to 2nd, 2nd to 1st by javascript push