# Mongodb Is there a plugin to query multi collection like "join"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Mongodb doesn't support multi collection query, like "left join" in SQL. It only support "populate", but it can't populate subdocument and find parent-document at the same time.

One line query code in SQL, while mongodb user has to query every parent document _id himself.

I have run into these question:
[How to populate other collection's subdocument in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199444/how-to-populate-other-collections-subdocument-in-mongoose)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075910/mongoose-cant-update-or-insert-subdocuments-array

I finally query every _id by myself in a forEach loop.

Is there a plugin to query multi collection like "join"? Or is there any better solution to multi collection query?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a plugin to query multi collection like "join"?

Some DB products have plug-ins that provide extra features, like PostGIS for Postgres. MongoDB does not have such a plug-in for JOINs. It is unlikely that such a plug-in will ever exist because MongoDB is designed *not* to have join support.

> mongoose...

So the one spot where there is "join-like" support are the drivers. *Some* drivers and wrappers (*like Morphia*), have support for opening a document and its related sub-documents from a different collection. However, in this case, the driver/tool is simply doing the work of performing multiple queries on your behalf.

This can easily generate too many queries.

> Or is there any better solution to multi collection query?

The only solution provided wholly within MongoDB is going to be via the Map / Reduce or [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) tools. Even with these tools, you are likely going to have to do multiple passes of the data and then write some scripts to stitch together this data. This will be a lot of work, but you're trying to do something that MongoDB doesn't like to do, so that's expected.

Another solution would be to leverage Hadoop. MongoDB has a Hadoop plug-in so you can run Hadoop over the existing data. Add in some Hadoop query tools like Hive and then you can get an SQL-Like query over the top. This will also be a lot of work, but will enable to run all sorts of SQL-like queries.