# Is there a way to index a document in mongoDB populating its references?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have these two collections:

```
Book: {
title: String,
description: String
author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
}

User: {
_id: (generated by mongo)
username: String
}
```

And I want to index Book for FTS. 
Can I do it in such a way that it will also be searchable by username even though the usernames are not explicitly stored in the books collection?

In other words, is it possible (or advisable) to index a populated collection?

Thanks

Comment: refer to these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate

Comment: So by adding index:true, the reference will become indexed within the collection?

Comment: No. It is not possible to do any kind of search ( FTS or otherwise ) on data contained on "username" ( or any other field ) from another collection. This is a "join", which is something MongoDB does not do ( excluding aggregation `$lookup` ), and "populate" is not really a join, but just a convenience wrapper around running separate lookup queries. You can only ever ask the database to search on data from one collection only at a time.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the clear answer!

Answer (score 1):

As Blakes Seven mentioned, it is not possible to index across collections.

In cases where this kind of full text search has been paramount to my application, the classic solution is to denormalize the field and included it in both collections. In this case, your `Book` collection would look like:

```
Book: {
  title: String,
  description: String
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'User',
    ### New field ###
    username: String
  },
}
```

Now you can index on `author.username`.

It is entirely dependent on your application whether or not that is a good idea. Downsides include synchronizing `username` across collections and adding unnecessary weight to each document.