# Population in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema:

```
var wishListSchema = new Schema({
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' }]
});
var wishList = mongoose.model('WishList', wishListSchema, 'WishList');
```

and i have this other mongoose schema:

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    "name":String,
    "description":String
});
var item= mongoose.model('Items', itemSchema, 'Items');
```

and this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "name":String, 
    "surname":String, 
    "wishList": { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'WishList' }
});
```

but when I get the User from database and I try to populate the wishList and items, the result of items is null

```
User.findOne({name:name})
    .populate({
        path:"wishList",
        populate: {
            path:"items"
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, userDb){
        console.log(userDb);
    });
```

The result is:

```
{
    _id: "56f85549334635c01b19bc37",
    name: "AAA",
    surname: "BBB"
    wishList: {
        _id: "56f85549334635c01b19bc39",
        __v: 0,
        items: [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a sub-document in mongoose after creating it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
User.findOne({name:name})
.populate({
    path:"wishList",
    select: "items"
})
.exec(function(err, userDb){
    console.log(userDb);
});
```