# How to use moongoose populate?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two schemas one book and other user

```
 let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    let book = new Schema({
        id: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: null},
        author: {type : Array, default: []},
        userId:{type:Array,default:[]},
        issued:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'users'}]
    });

    let user = new Schema({
       id: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: null},
       name:{type : String, default: null},
       address:{type : String, default: null}
    });
```

Issued property in book schema carries the detail for the user who issued book.

> Issued Property can be populated by using userId of book Schema and
>   matching userId of book schema with an Id of user Schema.

```
let user =  mongoose.model("Model", userSchema, "users");
let book = mongoose.model("book", bookSchema);

  book.find({}).populate('users').exec(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
           //Query is failing what wrong i am doing.
    });
```

I am not able to determine how can I fetch user detail.

I want object like:

```
{  
    id: 8888998898989,
    author: 'Author ',
    userId:['232323232332','ssssssss'],
    issued:[
             {'id':232323232332,'name':'User1'},
             {'id':ssssssss,'name':'User2'}
            ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.populate({ path: 'userId', model: 'users', select:'id name address' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the populate method with an object literal as following:

```
.populate({ path: 'id', model: 'ssers', select:'id name' })
```

you can use a lean() query so that you can modify the output and then perform your populate both fields to only keep **the field you want**:

```
.lean().populate('users', 'id name address')
```

More examples an be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it)  and [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)