# Call a related collection via populate

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I try to call a related list of logs for a certain user via [Mongoose populate.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) Who can help me with finishing the response?

These are the schemes:

```js
const logSchema = new Schema({
    logTitle: String,
    createdOn:
    { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
   });

const userSchema = new Schema({
    
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    logs: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'logs' }
     
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
mongoose.model('logs', logSchema);
```

Inspired by the Mongoose documentary (see above) and other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it) in relation to this subject I think I got pretty far in making a nice get. request for this user. I miss the expierence to 'translate it' to Express.

```html
const userReadLogs = function (req, res) {
    if (req.params && req.params.userid) {
        User1
            .findById(req.params.userid)
            .populate('logs') 
            .exec((err, user) => {
                if (!user) { }); // shortened
                    return;
                } else if (err) {
                    return; // shortened
                }

                response = {  //question
                    log: {  
                        user: user.logs 
                    }
                };

             res   
                    .status(200)
                    .json(response);
            });
    } else { }); // 

    }
};
```

The response in Postman etc would be something like this:

```html
{
    "log": {5a57b2e6f633ce1148350e29: logTitle1,
    
            6a57b2e6f633ce1148350e32: newsPaper44,
            
            51757b2e6f633ce1148350e29: logTitle3
    
}
```

Comment: can you post some example documents as well. 
Although it is a bad design, you are saving reference (_id) for logs inside a user document, and a reference (_id) of user in logs, You should only have it in logSchema and reference it accordingly `LogsModel.find({ ...query }).populate('postedBy').then( ...callback )`.

Comment: I thought making a nice job in the Schema 's of using the example of Mongoose Populate (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) In stead of 'writers' and 'stories', I used 'users' and 'logs'. I thinks it works the same way? The response (example documents) would be a list of logTitles for a specific userid in JSON format.

Comment: can you tell us what specifically the problem is, your question is pretty vague.

Comment: in my function userReadLogs there is a 'response = ..'. What  code I need to add to get my .json result? thanks in advance

Comment: What response are you getting right now?

Comment: now it is empty {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `logs` will not be a list of logs; it will be an `object`. If you want multiple logs for each user, you will need to store is as an `array`: `logs: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'logs' }]`

From the `Mongoose` docs: "*Populated paths are no longer set to their original _id , their value is replaced with the mongoose document returned from the database by performing a separate query before returning the results.*" In other words, in your `query` `user.logs` will be the `logs` `document` for each user. It will contain all the `properties`, in your case `logTitle`, `createdOn`, and `postedBy`.

Sending `user.logs` as `json` from the server is as easy as: `res.json(user.logs)`. So your query can look like this:

```
const userReadLogs = function (req, res) {
    if (req.params && req.params.userid) {
        User1
            .findById(req.params.userid)
            .populate('logs') 
            .exec((err, user) => {
                if (!user) { }); // shortened
                    return;
                } else if (err) {
                    return; // shortened
                }
                res.status(200).json(user.logs)
            });
    } else { }); // 

    }
};
```

I hope this makes it a little bit clearer!

Comment: Great! Please consider marking an answer as correct or upvote it if you find it useful, in order to help other community members that may encounter similar problems. You can read more about accepting and upvoting answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)