# Retrieving subdocument in mongoose and showing in html page

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am creating a shopping website using nodejs and mongoose.I want to retrieve usercart from User schema.

```
var Products = new Schema(
{
   name: {type: String, required: true},
   details: {type: String, required: true},
   category: {type: String, required: true},
   price: {type: Number, required: true},
   proimg: {data: Buffer ,type: String}
});

var usercart = new Schema({
   productId: {type: String, required: true}
});

var Users = new Schema({
   name: {type: String, required: true},
   email: {type: String, required: true,unique:true,trim:true},
   password: {type: String, required: true},
   address: {city:String,state:String},
   phone: {type: Number, required: true,unique:true},
   cart: [usercart]
});
```

I want all the product IDs stored in usercart and want to store the details of all products from product schema. I dont know how to retreive sub-document so pls help.

```
app.get('/view-cart',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
user.find({_id: 'sess.id'},'cart',function(err,usr){
   pro=usr.cart;
        console.log(pro);
        //
        // 
        //


        if(err) console.log("Error");
        else  res.render('view-cart', {
            "list" : pro
        });

});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a sub-document in mongoose after creating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it)  I think that post will tell you everything you need to know anout populating mongoose queries.

Answer (score 0):

With [mongodb 3.6 and above](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you can easily join nested field without using `$unwind`. I am not sure with the results but You can try somthing like below:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "usercard",
    "let": { "product_id", "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$productId", "$$product_id"] }}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "let": { "cardId", "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$cart", "$$cardId"] }}}
        ],
        "as": "cart"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "cart"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$cart" }
])
```