# How should I insert data in different collection of database in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm a beginner in this all stuff for creating rest api by Node.js with Mongodb.

Every time I get confused what is the difference between "ref" and "populate" in Mongodb and the main query I have is, how can I store different data in different collection created by us in Mongodb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate a sub-document in mongoose after creating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026486/how-to-populate-a-sub-document-in-mongoose-after-creating-it)

Comment: Kuldeep, this question would be immeasurably improved with the code you are working on at present. Currently it is very likely to close as Too Broad or Unclear. We need to see a [mcve].